# Manage Org Quota in CF

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

We have an old org for our which exceed quota after several month of teams usage, then we start to delete services manually which not used and this is not a simple job to run after Quota , not used service and very hard to manage it...

We have a new Org in CF for Our teams ( we use native CF- OS) .

Now we have a much bigger Quota, (memory, disk,routes etc) but if we do not do some cleanup job for a while the Quota will be exceeded after a few month again...

There is some service/capability in native CF to do some cleanup or shout down automatically for services/app which not used/called after some defined time (like after 2-3 month ) maybe stop them or even delete them .. king of "Watch Dog" ? Lets say I've the org admin rights ...

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize the [Cloud Foundry API](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/263/) to obtain usage information for a space and the associated apps and services. Write a script or small app for the evaluation, then run it with the serverless [IBM OpenWhisk on Bluemix](https://console.bluemix.net/openwhisk/). [It allows cron-like periodic execution of functions](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/openwhisk_alarms.html#openwhisk_catalog_alarm).